# How do i change panning angle on player 1s turn in friday night funkin?

Tags: mods, friday-night-funkin

I am trying to make a reskin over daddy dearest and the reskin in question is a lot shorter, and I want to change the camera position when it is his turn to fit his height, how do I change this?

Comment: Does 'fnf' refer to Friday Night Funkin`? If so, can anyone with sufficient reputation create a tag and edit this question?

Comment: MeanGreen Yes, it does refer to Friday night funkin